# Determining new posts from old posts in Javascript AngularJS, filter or not

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, angularjs

Okay, I am using WordPress and JSON API to make WordPress as a backend of my application, and now I am dealing with getting dates from post and add class if the post is new or not, and I am wonder if this is a job of a filter or just extend the object to add a property of new, basically iterating through the array of posts and adding a property of `isNew`

Can't get my logic right though.

Lets say I am getting posts from a `Post` service like so

```
$scope.posts = [];
Post.getPosts().then(function(posts){
  $scope.posts = posts;
});
```

Now before I do this : $scope.posts = posts, I want Angular to extend the properties of each post, adding `isNew`

```
var today = new Date();
var newMark = new Date();
newMark.setDate(newMark.getDate() - 5);

Post.getPosts(5).then(function (re) {
  angular.forEach(re.posts, function(post, key){
    var postDate = new Date(post.date);
    console.log(today - postDate < newMark); // lol, I don't have quite a logic here.
    // console.log(postDate - today < today - newMark);
  });
});
```

Lol, can't seem to think today.

Comment: what logic you want here console.log(today - postDate < newMark);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the property to true for all the posts whose post date is after the newMark, don't you ?

```
$scope.posts=[];
var newMark=new Date(Date.now() - 5 * 24 * 3600 *1000);

Post.getPosts(5)
.then(function (re) {
  // add a property to the model to tell whether is new 
  $scope.posts= re.posts.map(function(post){
    post.isNew=new Date(post.date) >= newMark;
    return post;
  });
});
```

Now you can bind the `posts` collection to your view and use the `ngClass` directive with the `isNew` property for example

Answer (score 1):

include [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
Post.getPosts(5).then(function (re) {
  var newMark = moment().subtract(5, 'days');
  for (var i in re.posts) {
    re.posts[i].isNew = moment(post.date) > newMark ? true : false;
  }
});
```

Comment: nice moment.js, but I will not be using this now.